# jquery uniform not styling ajax load elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, uniform

I am using jquery to load a remote page into a page.  The remote page contains some selects and inputs that are no longer styled due to the ajax load.  From what I could find I need to specify those again and update, but the below is not working.

```
// load the page into div
$('#show_comps').load('/process/show_comps.php');

// correct the uniform styling
$.uniform('select, input');
$.uniform.update();
```

EDIT :

```
$('#show_comps').load('/process/show_comps.php',
    function() {
        $('#show_comps').find('select').uniform(),
        $('#show_comps').find('input:checkbox').uniform()
    }
)
```

This corrected the checkboxes on the page, but the drop down is still not working (it changed style-wise, but not correct).

```
<select class="form-control input-medium select2me pull-right" onChange="App.scrollTo($(this.value), -60)" data-placeholder="Jump to computer...">
    <option value=""></option>
    ...and so on
```

2nd EDIT :

The drop down was using select2 plugin.  This is what I ended up with which works as expected.

```
$('#show_comps').load('/process/show_comps.php',
    function() {
        $('#show_comps').find('input').uniform();
        $('#comp_selection select').select2();
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what show_comps.php is outputting?

Comment: Hrm, still not enough information to go on. Are you able to reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

after ajax call when after data came use this

$('.elementClass').uniform();